# Prediction based on day / time with AI

Tags: artificial-intelligence, decision-tree

I did some digging but I couldn't find anything (maybe I just didn't know what do search exactly),
I'm in my final year of study and I am starting my final year project in Software engineering,
My plain is to (lets take smart house as an example) create a machine that will learn the householders habits and then do that action based on what they did (e.g: at Sunday, 7 AM turn on the boiler for 30 minutes).

What AI algorithms can I use to make it work?

I thought maybe decisions tree but I'm not sure it can work...
I also need algorithm that I can actually develop (or more accurate usable algorithm).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should ask your professor for suggestions and feedback. We can help with specific code problems, but "how should I design and implement my project" is too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I did asked him, he pointed me to ANN, but as far as i understand it doesn't fit my needs. And i don't ask how to implement my work, just which algorithms can be used.

Comment: Did you tell him that, any why you think so? You *may* be able to ask something like this over at AI Stack Exchange,
 but check that it's [on topic for that site first](http://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (I'm not active there so I'm not 100% sure).

Comment: Yes I did, also, the head of my department said that Neural Networks for a final project are impossible to create and it will cause me to fail... I will try what you pointed me to now